# It's the 14th of January. I still see sleighs

Tags: discussion, chat

It's the 14th of January. I still see sleighs when people depart from chat.

Christmas is over. When is it due to stop?

Comment: Are they CHRISTMAS sleighs or WINTER sleighs?

Comment: You tell me, you're a moderator ;)

Comment: We really don't know those sorts of things, those have to come from the SE staff.

Comment: I'm assuming, though, that it's winter related and not strictly a holiday  thing.

Comment: When Aslan returns to Narnia and the winter ends ?

Comment: It'll be winter in the Southern hemisphere in a few months, so I suspect not

Comment: They're winter sleighs, not Christmas sleighs (they started long before Christmas, and there's no reindeers or anything either). I'm going to remove them some time this week probably.

Comment: @balpha ok, thanks :) Add it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's Christmas-y about that sleigh/sled (there's no santa, no reindeers, no presents...) It's a winter goodie, not a Christmas goodie (yes, we [tend to ignore the southern hemisphere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159388/summer-in-saint-helena)). Anyway, it's gone now (after you get new JavaScript).